# videojs Flash Fallback Not Working In IE8

Tags: flash, video, fallback, video.js

I just recently started using html5 with videojs and I believe that I have everything working, however, the flash video fallback does not work with IE8 in WinXP. Also, its not just my site but the videos on the http://videojs.com/ site do not work in IE8 either.

So, I assume that this is a bug with the videojs flash player. For example, when I visit http://videojs.com/ with IE8 and play the video at the top of the page then no video is played but a black box is displayed in the video window instead while the video's audio does play in the flash player.  Nevertheless, when I go to other flash video sites then IE8 plays them fine.

Has anybody else noticed this and do you have any info on when this will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Its fixed. All that I did was turn hardware acceleration off in the local flash player running under IE8 in WinXP:

Right click on video when playing or paused > Settings > Uncheck "Enable hardware acceleration"

I actually had to change the setting while playing a Flash video that doesn't use videojs since IE8 froze up when trying to play Flash with videojs. It probably has something to do with the fact that I am running a virtualized image of WinXP under VirtualBox.

Now the Flash fallback works fine with videojs and I have lots of joy...