# VideoJS: .flv not playing in IE

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I am working with [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) (a jQuery video player).  When I add a `.flv` file to the player the VideoJS element works in Firefox/Chrome/Opera but is failing in Internet Explorer.

What can I do to allow the video to properly play in Internet Explorer 9?

HTML CODE:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://klaus.geekserver.net/ming-video/test.flv" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

I have posted a JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKING/5VsAh/).

Answer (score 1):

I know I am little late but if you are still looking for the answer, this will help you.

In your source tag change type from video/mp4 to video/flv and you are good to go.

this is the code example

`<source src="http://klaus.geekserver.net/ming-video/test.flv" type='video/flv' />`

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade my flash player on ie8.

Another thing may be this:
[videojs Flash Fallback Not Working In IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585439/videojs-flash-fallback-not-working-in-ie8)